# Post action to facebook bypassing activity log

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

How to post message through Open Graph facebook API to messages directly appear on user's timeline (bypassing activity log)? Is that possible at all?

Comment: No, you don't decide what show up on timeline.

Comment: It would be useful to get documentation links, etc. My purpose here is implement posting to messages appear directly on timeline or prove customer, that it isn't possible. All I found so far is quite dummy and can't be treated as 100% proof. So, I posted message here, maybe someone already researched that issue

Comment: I don't know the link but I know it is not possible